# jquery can't get input value from dynamically created field within a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

'This is a little strange, and different than what I can find in the forums, but I encounter this problem again and again when I work with jQuery.

I have code that calls ajax and creates (on success) an input like:

```
Start Date: <input type="text" id="gr_start_dt" size=10>
<button onclick="reassign_u();">Execute</button>
```

In the main body of the HTML, I have a function like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function reassign_u()
{
   alert($("#gr_start_dt").val());
}
</script>
```

This will alert to "undefined".

If I change the button in the ajax generated section to:

```
<button onclick="alert($('#gr_start_dt').val());">Execute</button>
```

it will alert with the value of the box.

I can get the value from outside of the function, but not within the function.

Am I missing something here? Is there some scope I'm not aware of with jquery and dynamically generated pages with ajax?

I'm using jquery 2.1.3 and 2.1.4, Firefox 39.

Comment: Your code works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/428vxt0c/. Something else must be causing your code to fail. I would suggest trying to separate your JS from your HTML .... that might help you figure out what that is.

Comment: You haven't recreated the scenario by using ajax, so I wouldn't automatically discount it with your jsfiddle. I've run into this many other times so it is not specific to this example.

Comment: Is any of those many instances somewhere online where we can take a look? I'd be glad to make an assessment and make some informed suggestions, if that is alright with you @J.R.

Comment: It's heavily firewalled and can only be run once authenticated, so that would be pretty much impossible. 
It's not particular to a particular page. It is a problem I seem to run into quite often using ajax, where the DOM element is complete within the ajax section of code, and missing parts outside of the ajax section.

Comment: I would be delighted to host for you  a minimal sample if you can provide the files.

Comment: Take a look at the page I have set up. What can I change to bring it as close to your scenario as possible? http://ezwich.net63.net/jr/

Comment: I've added it to a server with external access. It is a very very very scaled down page (there's literally hundreds of objects). This is barebones and still the problem persists.
http://sssc-serv.usask.ca/external/testing.php

Comment: I've added a duplicate function that calls the ajax to test if it is a problem with calling and recalling the function But that isn't the case. If you pop open the div box, then select a date, then hit the first execute, it sends it to the function that returns undefined. Then enter another value and hit the second execute that returns from the ajax code.

Comment: Also, you can browse the directory. I also saved the fetch.php as fetch.txt so you can see the contents.

Comment: I think I know what's going on. **You're clearing the contents of `#invoice_detail_content`, which contains the text box, before attempting to read the value,** *And since the alert causes a long-enough-pause for new content to load, the next line `console.log(..)` makes it appear that the textbox was there when the alert fired -- just change the alert to a `console.log(...)` and the results would be different.* Suggestions: 1. make the `alert()` the first statement in `reassign_user2();` or better still 2. do not clear `#invoice_detail_content` until the new content (ajax) has been received.

Comment: Ah, good catch. It does work if I comment out the clearing statement. This was really hard to track down, as the DOM still contained the element but it had no value. So now I know that the element won't be destroyed, just its value. I have the same problem happening in another page that is unrelated and doesn't have a clear statement. I'll have to go through and see if I can track down if there's something similar going on. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad I could be of help. Just so you know **the DOM did not have the element -- the `alert()` made it look like the element was present;** `alert` statements can lead into many issues such as this. If instead of the `alert()` you had a `console.log()`, perhaps you'd have figured this out quicker. Let us know how it goes with those other pages. Pleasure was all mine @J.R.

Comment: There actually is a console.log in the function. I uncommented the clearing statement and checked, and the element is still defined with selector #group_start_dt. If only I could attach a screen shot. It's still up if you want to check.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is because when the javascript function was cached into the browser the element $("#gr_start_dt") is not yet defined. And calling the function will just call the function that was cached having the undefined element inside the alert function.

So why not do it like this:

below is the html

```
Start Date: <input type="text" id="gr_start_dt" size=10>
<button onclick="reassign_u($('#gr_start_dt'));">Execute</button>
```

below is the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function reassign_u(el)
{
   alert($(el).val());
}
</script>
```

Comment: You're missing something important there. You might want to review the above code @PeterKA

Comment: Just think it through. Here is another example: http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/428vxt0c/1/ ... when the page loads, the element does not exist .... why does it work and his does not?

Comment: Again you are using append, and this is NOT what I am doing. The element is being added using ajax, which may use append but it is a separate entity in itself.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the the line: `$("#invoice_detail_content").html('');` from the following function should resolve the issue. This line removes the the textbox in question.

```
function reassign_user2() { 
    $("#action_menu_container").hide();
    $("#invoice_detail_content").html(''); //<== REMOVE THIS
    $("#invoice_detail").show();
    $("#loading").show();

    console.log($("#group_start_dt"));

    alert($("#group_start_dt").val());


    $.ajax({
        url: "fetch.php",
        cache: false,
        method: "POST",
        data: {
            action: 'reassign_group',
            parameters: JSON.stringify(parameters)                        
        }                              
    })
    .done(function(result) {                                       
        $("#loading").hide();
        result = result.trim();
        if(result)
        {
            $("#invoice_detail_content").html(result);
        }
        else
        {
            $("#invoice_detail").hide();
            show_invoices($("#invoice_status_select").val());
        }
    })
    .fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
        $("#loading").hide();
        alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );                                                 
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I'm taking a bit of a stab at this so hopefully I don't get down voted :(, though I believe I have the answer to this question.

When the DOM tree is created on the first page load all of the javascript events are bound to the all their respective elements, thus your .val() isn't attaching to any dynamically generated elements, but, one thing I have noticed, is that if you dynamically add some javascript with that dynamically created element it will run its binding process right then and there and still work, which is what you have done by putting the alert($(element).val()) directly on the dynamically generated element.

Hopefully this helps you, if not somebody out there. I realized the answer is a bit late.

Answer (score -1):

I'm pretty sure creating things with JQuery/AJAX still causes it to enter the DOM, which means it can be gotten with `$('selector')`. So it should be just as straightforward usual.

I used:

```
<script>
    function on_clicked() {
       alert($("#text_input").val());
    }
</script>

<input type="text" id="text_input" size=10>
<button onclick="on_clicked();">Execute</button>
```

Working JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/usqn8ut4/).

I found that you have to declare the function before setting it to the `onclick` attribute. Which makes sense. Otherwise I don't see any other big problems.

## Update

I am now making the `<form>` element "asynchronously" (I used a timeout to simulate AJAX. As long as the callback is declared before and in scope, it works fine.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/usqn8ut4/1/)

I've replicated what you are saying as well as I can, and it still works.

Comment: The function is always defined before as it is in the original HTML file. It is ajax that loads the element and then is executed. I can access the element using jsquery if it is within the ajax loaded segment, but not outside of it. Even if I add a console.log call with the element within the function, it sees it but has no value assigned to it. If I call a console.log right after it is loaded from ajax, I can see the value. Why are these different if they are both accessing DOM? Does ajax have a particular scope?

Comment: I've worked around this in other instances by calling from the ajax loaded section or calling elements themselves with $(this), but now I have an instance where I can't do that (or don't want to do it because I don't want to have to write a function for every different page).

Comment: As long as the function is **globally** loaded, the callback seems to find it fine. You can check if the function is defined in your scope by opening your JavaScript console and checking its value.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the scope of the function. The function is as global as it can get. It is not grabbing the DOM object correctly. That is what this is all about.

Answer (score -1):

It works for me. May be you should put the js function in the same file from which you make the AJAX call.

here's the code

index.php

```
<head>
            function doSomeTheing() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'test01.php',
                    success: function (mydata) {
                        $('#container').html(mydata);
                    }
                });
            }

            function reassign_u()
            {
                alert($("#gr_start_dt").val());
            }
</head>
<body>
        <input type="button" id="abc" onclick="doSomeTheing()" value="test">
        <div id="container">

        </div>
</body>
```

test.php contains

```
<?php

echo 'Start Date: <input type="text" id="gr_start_dt" size=10>
<button onclick="reassign_u();">Execute</button>';
```

Comment: This can't be added to the same file as the ajax call because it needs to be different in the context in which it is called. If it is called in one page, it is under that context (different variables incorporated within the function depending on the needs for that page). This was supposed to be generic so that I can call a function and only need to know that the element I need is #gr_start_dt.

Comment: It should work even if AJAX was in a different context can you post your project directory structure and how you writ the path of the URL of `$.ajax`. @J.R.

Comment: I don't think you understand what I mean. If I want to trigger the function call in Invoices, it should pertain to invoices and run the appropriate procedures for Invoices using that date. If I want it in the context of group membership, it should run with different parameters that are determined by the page it is on, not by the ajax page.

Comment: @J.R. you can put the input element and button on a php file and include it in the place you want this elements to appear in.